# Error encountered after upgrading to Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR7 from Hoxton.SR4

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

Using Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR4` and Spring Boot `2.2.9.RELEASE` libraries, my Spring Boot microservice starts up correctly and runs just fine when running against localstack in my local environment, but when I upgrade to `Hoxton.SR7`, I get the stack trace below:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:69)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:402)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.annotation.OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.matches(OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.java:38)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:469)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.acme.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1227)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:80)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
2020-08-05 | 17:42:13.698 | main                 |  WARN | com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      | Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/meta-data/instance-id). Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:69)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:402)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.annotation.OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.matches(OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.java:38)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:469)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.acme.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1227)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:80)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

What new or additional configurations/code do I need to include to turn this EC2 checking off in my local environment when running against localstack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a warning message logged directly from AWS SDK and inside Spring Cloud AWS we have no control over it. Following [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#amazon-sdk-configuration), just turn this warning off by adding a line to your `application.properties` config file:

```
logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error
```

Comment: I encountered this when trying to debug why ```@ConfigurationProperties``` objects are not binding to property sources and return null values when we try to reference them in our ```@Configuration``` classes to create AWS client beans. I've logged this issue at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/641. I saw in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/640 that the 2.2.3.RELEASE moved away from ```ApplicationContextAware``` to ```BeanFactoryPostProcessor``` to manage AWS beans and that this might be breaking the application startup. Any ideas?